# Citation doesn't respect page layout

Tags: citing

I can't understand why citation are out of the margin. The result I have is in the pic.

[image]

This is the code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,twoside,12pt]{book}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[breaklinks]{hyperref}

\makeatletter
\renewenvironment{thebibliography}[1]
  {%
    \chapter*{\bibname}%
    \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\bibname}%
    \@mkboth{\MakeUppercase\bibname}{\MakeUppercase\bibname}%
    \list{}%
    {%
      \settowidth\labelwidth{}%
      \leftmargin\labelwidth
      \advance\leftmargin\labelsep
      \@openbib@code
      \usecounter{enumiv}%
      \let\p@enumiv\@empty
      \renewcommand\theenumiv{\@arabic\c@enumiv}%
    }%
    \sloppy
    \clubpenalty4000
    \@clubpenalty \clubpenalty
    \widowpenalty4000%
    \sfcode`\.\@m%
  }%
  {%
    \def\@noitemerr
    {\@latex@warning{Empty `thebibliography' environment}}%
    \endlist%
  }   % Finisce qui la ridefinizione di thebibliography

\makeatother

\begin{document}

Gallia est omnis divisa in partes tres, quarum unam incolunt Belgae, aliam Aquitani, tertiam qui ipsorum lingua Celtae, nostra Galli appellantur. Hi omnes lingua, institutis, legibus inter se differunt. Gallos ab Aquitanis Garunna flumen, a Belgis Matrona et Sequana dividit \cite{Wine:2015}. Horum omnium fortissimi sunt Belgae, propterea quod a cultu atque humanitate provinciae longissime absunt minimeque ad eos mercatores saepe commeant atque ea, quae ad effeminandos animos pertinent, important proximique sunt Germanis, qui trans Rhenum incolunt, quibuscum continenter bellum gerunt. Qua de causa Helvetii quoque reliquos Gallos virtute praecedunt, quod fere cotidianis proeliis cum Germanis contendunt, cum aut suis finibus eos prohibent aut ipsi in eorum finibus bellum gerunt. Eorum una pars, quam Gallos obtinere dictum est, initium capit a flumine Rhodano, continetur Garunna flumine, Oceano, finibus Belgarum, attingit etiam ab Sequanis et Helvetiis flumen Rhenum, vergit ad septentriones.


\end{document}
```

The citation I used is:

```
@article{Wine:2015,
 author={International Organization of Vine and Wine},
 year={2015},
}
```

Comment: this is really the same as your previous question: [How can I split \cite in 2 lines?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/278458).  it would be better to add this example to that question so that everything is together.

Comment: Please, add the code to your previous question, together with the bibliographic entry.

Comment: yes, I deleted that question because was misplaced

Comment: I used `BibDesk` for the bibliographic so I don't know which is the code. I will add the `\cite` I used.

Comment: You seem to use an author-year citation style, but there's no package doing that. I tried adding `natbib` and a proper bib style, but I cannot reproduce the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

by default \cite is placed in an \hbox adding

```
\let\@cite@ofmt\relax
```

after your existing `\makeatletter` stops that boxing and allows it to break.